# jQuery autocomplete with multiple ajax'd values

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

been following the documentation from the UI site, and looked at a number of tutorials and got my code sort of working, it ajax's in the list of terms I want, and you can select one and it places the value and then ", ". However, afterwards it doesn't prompt again for a second value.

Also, when I enter a partial and say 10 entries pop up, tabbing just goes to the next form field, not sure what's wrong with my .bind, perhaps a setting? If anyone wouldn't mind taking a look, it'd be much appreciated!

```
function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }

        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

       jQuery('#tagSearch')
            .bind('keydown', function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                         jQuery(this).data('autocomplete').menu.active) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                    }
            })
           .autocomplete({
              autoFocus: true,
              source: function(request, add) {
                    console.log('source');
                    jQuery.getJSON('/get-tags-like.php?term_start=' + request.term, function(response) {
                        var possibleTerms = [];

                        jQuery.each(response, function(i, val) {
                            possibleTerms.push(val.name + ' ' + '(' + val.count + ')');
                        });

                        add(jQuery.map(possibleTerms, function(item) {
                            console.log(possibleTerms);
                            return item;
                        }));        
                    });
              },
              focus: function() {
                  console.log('focus');
                return false;
              },
              select: function(event, ui) {
                  console.log('select');
                  var terms = split(this.value);

                  terms.pop();

                  terms.push(ui.item.value);

                  terms.push('');

                  this.value = terms.join(',');

                  // At this point, example:
                  // Sony (5)
                var currentVal = this.value;

                  // Sony (5) - Gets inserted as "Sony"
                  currentVal = currentVal.replace(/\s\(.\)/, '');

                  this.value = currentVal;

                  return false;
              },
              minLength: 2
           });
```

Comment: Would the autocomplete's binding of the keydown event interfere with yours?

Answer (score 1):

> However, afterwards it doesn't prompt again for a second value.

Make sure you're typing more than 2 characters. The function passed to `search` is preventing a search with less than two characters from causing a search:

```
search: function() {
      var term = extractLast(this.value);

      if (term.length < 2) {
          return false;
      }
},
```

---

> Also, when I enter a partial and say 10 entries pop up, tabbing just goes to the next form field, not sure what's wrong with my .bind, perhaps a setting?

The `bind` at the beginning is attempting to prevent the user from tabbing from the field **when an autocomplete candidate is highlighted**. With a single value autocomplete, this usually is not a problem because first the menu item is selected, placed in the `input`, and then focus is lost.

This changes when you want multiple values in the `input`. We want to stop that default action of `keydown` that changes focus to the next input field.

`autocomplete` has an [`autoFocus`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus) option that will be useful here. It will ensure that a candidate is *always* selected when the user hits tab after typing.

I'm not able to exactly replicate your situation, but I've created a demo that doesn't exhibit either of the problems that you are experiencing (all I've really done is change the source and add the `autoFocus` option): http://jsfiddle.net/zTVKC/

Comment: Thanks! It still isn't working however your jsfiddle gave me a lot of insight, I couldn't get ajax working at all without using getJSON. Now I've noticed after the first entry, it does an ajax call for the second and gets the object, but doesn't add or populate a dropdown :-/. I removed the search function entirely to get rid of that possibility.

Comment: @John: Interesting... Is it what you're searching for maybe? If you search for the same thing twice (which should return the same results), does that make any difference?

Comment: Nope, same thing always, gets the results and doesn't display them after 1 result. I can delete everything, and start from scratch and again, it works for the first and not the second. I must have something messed up with the comma delimiter I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Firebug to debug through the AJAX success?

Comment: Yes, if it's the first item the json returns a proper json object, however after the first comma it returns "true" instead of actual terms. Bizarre.

Comment: Is your server-side code returning `true`, or is that the result of the post-processing that happens in the callback?

Comment: Has to be the result of the callback, the server side php always returns a json encoded string. Updated code in original post. (Truly appreciate the help!) -- Update - It's recognizing the second term as the first, second instead of just second. So looking into how to fix it now.

Comment: No problem, I'd like to figure it out too. I see your edits... You shouldn't need the call to `.map()`. Is this code at a public URL somewhere?

Comment: I fixed it actually! By making request.term = extractLast(request.term) at the beginning of the source function. I appreciate all the help again!